# How to create a variable hyperlink in an R Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

In my shiny app, I'm trying to create a hyperlink that opens an html file, created from an R Markdown file, to a certain section based on the current tab of the app the user is on.

Here's an excerpt from the ui and server code I'm using.

```
ui <- fluidPage(title = "App Title",
                dashboardPage(title = "App Title",
                              dashboardHeader(tags$li(a(href = paste0('Help_File.html', textOutput(page), target="_blank", icon("question"), title = "Help"), class = "dropdown")),
                              dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
                                                           menuItem(text = 'Tab 1', tabName = 'tab1'),
                                                           menuItem(text = 'Tab 2', tabName = 'tab2'),
                                                           menuItem(text = 'Tab 3', tabName = 'tab3')
                                                           )
                                               )

server <- function(input, output, session) {

                   output$page <- renderText({
                                  if(input$tabs == 'tab1') {'#page_1'}
                                  else if (input$tabs == 'tab2') {'#page_2'}
                                  else if (input$tabs == 'tab3') {'#page_3'}
                                  else ''
                                             })
                                            }
```

When I run the app, I get the error "ERROR: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'".  If I put single quotes around `page` in the `textOutput` function in the ui, the app runs but the file doesn't open.  I think either the `textOuput` function is wrong or the `renderText` function in the server is wrong but I'm not sure what the correct syntax is.

Comment: Have you looked at `shiny::downloadLink`?

Comment: There is also `shiny::a` for a standard *href*

Comment: Do either of those allow the link to be a variable string?

Comment: They will both render as a hyperlink with the text you assign, why don't you experiment and try for yourself?

Comment: I’ll give them a try.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `renderText` doesn't just have  text as output but rather a complete html object. In this case you want to use `renderUI` for the complete `a` object. And let the href be dynamicly generated within this. Like this

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
ui <- fluidPage(title = "App Title",
                dashboardPage(title = "App Title",
                              header = dashboardHeader(tags$li(uiOutput("page"), class = "dropdown")),
                              sidebar = dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
                                                           menuItem(text = 'Tab 1', tabName = 'tab1'),
                                                           menuItem(text = 'Tab 2', tabName = 'tab2'),
                                                           menuItem(text = 'Tab 3', tabName = 'tab3')
                                                           )
                                               ),
                              body = dashboardBody(div())
                )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$page <- renderUI({
    a(href = paste0(
      'Help_File.html', 
      if(input$tabs == 'tab1') {'#page_1'}
      else if (input$tabs == 'tab2') {'#page_2'}
      else if (input$tabs == 'tab3') {'#page_3'}
      else ''), 
      target="_blank", 
      style = "color:#FFF;",
      icon("question"), 
      title = "Help",
      "Help")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick!  One side effect seems to be that the icon is now at the very top right corner of the dashboard header instead of having a little space to the right and being more centered from top to bottom.  I can shift it back to the left by defining a margin but is there anything I can use to shift it back down so that it’s aligned in the middle of the header?

Comment: it is not the best way but you can add `style = "vertical-align: middle;line-height: 50px;"` to the li object after `class = "dropdown"`

Comment: Works for me.  Thanks again!