# Need to display dynamic text generated from server onto UI within a TextArea(with syntax highlighting)

Tags: html, r, shiny, codemirror

I am trying to push a randomly generated string onto a textarea on UI. New to HTML/Shiny/JS but I know a few basics.

My end goal is to use CodeMirror ([Whole download](http://codemirror.net/codemirror.zip)) or ShinyAce editor classes to add syntax highlighting to the textarea but I am unable to output strings from server into the textarea. I wish to push a certain R Code in `textStringToDisplay` and need syntax highlighting.

Please put the following files in the www folder of the app.R:

1. [codemirror.css](https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/blob/master/lib/codemirror.css)
2. [cobalt.css](https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/blob/master/theme/cobalt.css)
3. codemirror.js (I could not find
       this file on GitHub, please use the download link above, extract and
       look in the lib folder)
4. [r.js](https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/blob/master/mode/r/r.js)

Please let me know if you need more information or if I should rephrase any parts of this. Thanks in advance.

```
library(shiny)

if (interactive()) {

  ui <- shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
      tags$head(tags$title("Title"),
                tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "codemirror.css"),
                tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "cobalt.css"),
                tags$script(src = "codemirror.js"),
                tags$script(src = "r.js")
      ),
      tags$textarea(id="textBox", name = "Feedback", textOutput(outputId = "textStringToDisplay")),
      tags$script(
        'var editorR = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textBox, {
        mode: "r",
        lineNumbers: true,
        smartindent: true
});
        editorR.setOption("theme", "cobalt");
        editorR.setSize("50%","100%");')))

  server <- function(input, output){
    output$textStringToDisplay <- renderText(paste0(sample(letters,15),collapse = ""))
  }

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my final implementation. Would like to thank @Bertil for his suggestion regarding `renderUI`. Had to use `shinyjs` package and the `runjs` function to get the JS script running. Also it only works when paired with an event (like clicking a button). Do not know how to trigger it when the app loads(will post another question about this sometime later).

```
library(shiny) 
library(shinyjs)

if (interactive()) {
     ui <- shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
      useShinyjs(),
      tags$head(tags$title("Title"),
                tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "codemirror.css"),
                tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "cobalt.css"),
                tags$script(src = "codemirror.js"),
                tags$script(src = "r.js")
      ),
      actionButton("btn1","Click to see code"),
      uiOutput(outputId = "textStringToDisplay")))
     server <- function(input, output){
    output$textStringToDisplay <- renderUI(
      tags$textarea(id="textBox", name = "Feedback", paste0(sample(letters,15),collapse = "")))

    ButtonPressCounter <- 0

    observeEvent(input$btn1,
                 {
                   ButtonPressCounter <<- ButtonPressCounter + 1 # Need it to happen only once
                   if(ButtonPressCounter <= 1){
                     shinyjs::runjs(
                       'var editorR = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textBox, {
                       mode: "r",
                       lineNumbers: true,
                       smartindent: true});
                       editorR.setOption("theme", "cobalt");
                       editorR.setSize("100%","100%");')
                   }
                 })
       }
     shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have commented out you css and java scripts because I don't the where the problem. Your problem is the same as in this question

[How to create a variable hyperlink in an R Shiny App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47665179/how-to-create-a-variable-hyperlink-in-an-r-shiny-app/47669403#47669403)

Here is a working version of your code

```
library(shiny)

if (interactive()) {

  ui <- shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
      tags$head(tags$title("Title")
                # tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "codemirror.css"),
                # tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "cobalt.css"),
                # tags$script(src = "codemirror.js"),
                # tags$script(src = "r.js")
      ),
      uiOutput(outputId = "textStringToDisplay")
#       tags$script(
#         'var editorR = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textBox, {
#         mode: "r",
#         lineNumbers: true,
#         smartindent: true
# });
#         editorR.setOption("theme", "cobalt");
#         editorR.setSize("50%","100%");')
))

  server <- function(input, output){
    output$textStringToDisplay <- renderUI(
      tags$textarea(id="textBox", name = "Feedback", paste0(sample(letters,15),collapse = "")))
  }

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Bertil, I know this works but was hoping to include the syntax highlighting editor class on the textarea element.

Comment: I don't really understand your problem then. With your code their wasn't any text in the text area now it is. If you add your js files I am sure the higlightning will work. It was just not their the problem was in your code. I will look into more this evening (CET)

Comment: When I add back the js and css files, it still shows the same output i.e. without any syntax highlighting and without cobalt theme. I was also baffled by this behaviour. Thanks!!