# How to trigger JS Script when shiny app loads

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, codemirror, shinyjs

I wrote this code to apply the editor class on the textarea with id = "textBox". Applying the editor class needs a javascript code to run and was looking for a way to bind the javascript run to the event of starting the app (or when the app loads). Essentially I would like to run the js when the app loads without the need to bind it to a button press as it is presently implemented. I do not know how to refer to the app load event. The button implementation was the best I could come up with and have spent considerable amount of time before asking.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47693748/need-to-display-dynamic-text-generated-from-server-onto-ui-within-a-textareawit) question for details on how to get the code running.

Let me know if you need anymore info on this. Would be happy to oblige. Thanks in advance.

```
library(shiny) 
library(shinyjs)

if (interactive()) {
     ui <- shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
      useShinyjs(),
      tags$head(tags$title("Title"),
                tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "codemirror.css"),
                tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "cobalt.css"),
                tags$script(src = "codemirror.js"),
                tags$script(src = "r.js")
      ),
      actionButton("btn1","Click to see code"),
      uiOutput(outputId = "textStringToDisplay")))
     server <- function(input, output){
    output$textStringToDisplay <- renderUI(
      tags$textarea(id="textBox", name = "Feedback", paste0(sample(letters,15),collapse = "")))

    ButtonPressCounter <- 0

    observeEvent(input$btn1,
                 {
                   ButtonPressCounter <<- ButtonPressCounter + 1 # Need it to happen only once
                   if(ButtonPressCounter <= 1){
                     shinyjs::runjs(
                       'var editorR = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textBox, {
                       mode: "r",
                       lineNumbers: true,
                       smartindent: true});
                       editorR.setOption("theme", "cobalt");
                       editorR.setSize("100%","100%");')
                   }
                 })
       }
     shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server) }
```

Answer (score 2):

To run javascript code on opening the app, you don' t need to put the code in an observer. If you replace your server with the following code, you will see that the log will contain the line `"hello, this code has run."`

```
  server <- function(input, output){
    output$textStringToDisplay <- renderUI(
      tags$textarea(id="textBox", name = "Feedback", paste0(sample(letters,15),collapse = "")))

    shinyjs::runjs(
      'console.log("hello, this code has run.");
       var editorR = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textBox, {
                       mode: "r",
                       lineNumbers: true,
                       smartindent: true});
                       editorR.setOption("theme", "cobalt");
                       editorR.setSize("100%","100%");')
  }
```

Although the next line in the log is `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: CodeMirror`, so I guess there is something missing from your code?

Hope this helps!

Comment: The reference error is because a few javascript and css files are not present in your app's www folder. Would you mind adding them and trying again. I tried your solution and the runjs does not run automatically. I had tried this before. You can find the files in the link in the question above. Thanks!!

Comment: I was able to get JS to run on app start using the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42434168/336001